# Terminal Shortcut Key not respecting keyboard layout

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, dvorak

I just installed 11.04 and am using the dvorak keyboard layout.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up the terminal it doesn't bring it up, but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> (the key that would be t in qwerty) it brings up a terminal.

I have no other keyboard layouts installed, but have switched caps lock and control.

In the **Keyboard Shortcuts** configuration it shows up as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch a terminal.

I would like the terminal shortcut to respect the keyboard layout.

Comment: What is the output of `gconftool --get /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/run_command_terminal`, and what letter is reported by `xev | grep XLookupString` when you press the T key?

Comment: `<Control><Alt>t`
`XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (74) "t"`

Also, the keyboard shortcuts work in applications just fine, and <Control><#> works for switching desktops, etc.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards